# How to filter listview using webpart?

Tags: filter, content-query-web-part, content-search-web-part

We have a list view webpart on a page.

I want to create a textbox webpart and pass data into the list view webpart and filter it based on this data.

Is there OOTB method? Or do I develop a VS webpart?

Comment: any answer to this please?